# Html file not reading external js file

Tags: html

my html file that when i run it on my pc locally it never gets the javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Unless someone has had the exact same experience, this seems like it would be difficult to answer without more details. Does the script work if embedded locally? Is your browser blocking scripts? Maybe post the script code.

Comment: Also,have you looked at the console for any errors?

Comment: yes all files are in the same folder. i will put up the js file

Comment: You're using a relative path, this is probably where the problem comes from, but we can't really tell by the few information you gave us.

Comment: “All files are in the same folder”? You do realize that the HTML file is looking for the script in its parent folder? That’s what `../` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the order.

first css's { yours and and bootstrap css or others }
then  javascripts { jquery and|or bootstrap js and|or yours }

problably will load fine

Answer (score 0):

I guess basically the .js file must be present in a parent directory/folder  w.r.t to the index.html.

Basically following should be your folder structure according to 
Reference of script.js

[image: Directory Structure]

app
   |
   |---- script.js
   |
   |----- html
                  |
                  |----- index.html

Just to add of you have kept the index.html & script.js in same folder just remove  `../` as it moves one level up the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

By using `src="../script.js"`, you ask to your navigator to look in the parent folder.

As you said all your files are in the same folder, you should replace the source value by :

- 'script.js' (relative path)
- 'C/.../yourProject/script.js'(full path)